# Single value input control not visible on JR Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have two parameters in report:

1. ***week*** ---> has ***isForPrompting="true"*** property
2. ***year*** ---> has ***isForPrompting="true"*** property

But when I add a single value input control and run the same report on *JasperReports Server*, only a pop up window is opening up and not the the single value input control.

Also If I add a single value input control to my other reports, its showing up when I run the reports on *JR Server*.

I really don't understand why the single value input control is not showing up for the current report when everything is running well on *iReport* designer?

Comment: Did you create the input controls in JasperReports Server? What kind of input controls are they (text, single-select radio, etc)?

Comment: i created an single value input control of datatype number

Comment: Have you double-checked your data sources for your input controls?

Comment: yes. i double checked my data sources for my input controls. The input controls i have is single value no query and of type integer.

Comment: @SivaRaparla Having a similar issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most common problem: Your input control doesn't match exactly. The input control ID has to match the parameter. Remember that it's case sensitive.

Comment: on ireport the paramete name is week

on jasper i selected an input control of prompt text 'week', and Parameter name also as 'week'

but still i am getting the same pop up window with no single value input box. Just an empty pop up box.

Comment: @mdahlman  : Having a similar issue. Were you able to resolve this?